# Angular 2 Beta and Kendo UI Pro

Tags: kendo-ui, angular, kendo-chart

Is there an example of Kendo UI working with Angular 2 Beta?  Telerik's site shows the alpha way of doing it which doesn't mesh with beta.  If anyone has been able to get it to work can you send me an example or a doc of it's setup for ppl new to angular 2 beta.  The thing I care about the most is charts.

Comment: There shouldn't be much difference between alpha and beta, what's the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure how to add a modal window or chart to my project.  I tried following the example on my local machine but it didn't show anything.  No errors either.  I created a folder called js and added the jquery.min.js, kendo.angular2.min.js and kendo.all.min.js to the folder and referenced them in the index.html but how do I use them in my components?

Comment: I have no idea. I thought Telerik's site explains it. I might have been able to help with issues caused by changes since alpha.

Comment: The biggest change between the alpha and the beta is the addition of `angular2-polyfills.js`. You will need to include this script **before** the angular 2 bundle. This can also be found in `angular/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js`. Without this file the site will simply be blank and you will get no errors. Try adding this and see if that helps.

Comment: There is an open source alternative you might be interested in called PrimeNG, http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3763 Charts will come in a month or so.